# How to understand EAV-related PHP-Code

Tags: eav

By seeing Magento wonderful functionality I have seen interested on it and learned Magento.
Previously i worked on dotnet.

In Magento i have learned the flow and its structure.
Now i am struck with understanding PHP code and Magento built in functions.
I can do blocks and layouts customization.
But could not understand PHP and Magento fuunctions relates with EAV.

So i request you to please let me know how can i understand code with tables.
like order related issues, if i want to do modifications i could not reach the tables
it relates.

Please provide me some best tutorials for understanding advanced magento.

Comment: plz help me. beginners can learn only from u.

Comment: After 3 years coding in Magento, I just learned about phpStorm. Amazing IDE for its low price. Watching YouTube videos only scratches the surface. Also, EAV could be considered MySql/database programming, not php.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few simple Google searches would point you in the right direction. Some useful resources are as follows:

[Magento for Developers: Part 1 - Introduction to Magento](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-1-introduction-to-magento)

This covers an introduction to Magento, the Magento config, controller dispatch, layouts, blocks & templates, models and ORM basics, setup resources, advanced ORM (EAV) as well as varien data. (In part 1 - 8).

Another great place to feed your brain is:

[Alan Storm's Blog: Magento Articles for Professional Developers](http://alanstorm.com/category/magento)

Magento's site also offers a whole bunch of downloadable resources:

[User Guides and eCommerce Tips](http://www.magentocommerce.com/resources/magento-user-guide)

Including user guides, designer's guides as well as other useful resources for maintaining a successful e-commerce site.

And last, but certainly not least (and this one in particular I knew about before starting any form of development with Magento - **note:** this is a direct .PDF download):

[Conquer the 5 Most. Common Magento Coding. Issues to Optimize Your Site for Performance](http://www.google.co.za/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCMQFjAA&url=http://info.magento.com/rs/magentocommerce/images/Conquer_the_5_Most_Common_Magento_Coding_Issues_to_Optimize_Your_Site_for_Performance.pdf&ei=llmRU4zLDazA7Abfu4GIAQ&usg=AFQjCNE8guhja6rmBFHbRE4_AABG7Qv3Og&bvm=bv.68445247,d.ZGU&cad=rja)

What you need to understand is that Magento is not something you can "learn" everything about in a week, month, or even a year. It is an amazing platform with literally endless extendability and will involve life-long learning :)

There are plenty more resources available online, you'll need to have a look further for yourself. The Magento StackExchange in particular is your bread and butter when it comes to diagnosing problematic code, be sure to read these pages:

[How to Ask](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask)

[Help Center](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help)

I can assure you, over 50% of the questions you may have are likely already answered here. So be sure to make use of the site's wonderful [search function](https://magento.stackexchange.com/search).

Good luck & have fun.

Answer (score 2):

You should go through the magento world on internet. Navigate some website and blogs to know about magento all structure and functionality.

please go to the link: `http://www.siteground.com/tutorials/magento/structure.htm`

```
http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/2_-_magento_concepts_and_architecture/magento-folder-structure


http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magentos-theme-hierarchy
```

and also go to some magento certified persons blog to know about different type of customization.

```
http://inchoo.net/category/ecommerce/magento/
```

the above link where you can get all live running code and well know about the functions in magento.

Comment: Thnx for providing informn. I am aware of magento folder structure and its functionality. I suffered with customization with php code and tables linked.

Comment: Dont' forgot to accept my answer, hope this will definitely helps you :)